# Create a persistent pop up floating window using JavaScript/HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, quickblox

I've been looking around, but I can't think of the correct terminology to describe what I want (and hence get the results that I want from searching).

I'm going to be integrating the QuickBlox video chat into an existing web app. I've been asked to display the video window in a type of persistent floating window that will allow the user to continue using the website while they still have the video chat window open and chatting with the person (eg they could be chatting with a trainer, who might ask them to visit a specific page).

Is this type of thing possible with html/js/css? I need this special pop up window to be persistent and stay connected to the video chat.

Comment: In terms of the CSS, I'm guessing you'll probably want something with `position: fixed;`. If there will be different pages visited, those will probably have to be changed within in iframe.

Comment: If your site is a Single Page App (no page refresh) then you could fix a chat box in a corner. However if your site does have regular links and the pages get reloaded then you could try storing data in a cookie to load the chat window with every page load.

Comment: One idea I was kinda thinking was having something like a split screen. Where one part is the main site area where pages change etc, the other would be part with the chat stuff, but have this like 1px high or something at the bottom and it never changes. But even that I'm not quite sure how to do. The app uses the Laravel framework, and I'm thinking might involve some funky messing with the whole blade system or something.

Comment: That sounds like regular (non-iframes) frames to me (though I rarely see those used these days :-)).

Comment: Yea I probably don't want to use the old frames, since they're now deprecated. Was hoping there'd be some sort of nifty css/js way to do it, but looks like there may not be.